# Need help in java converting mp4 video to wmv video

Tags: java, mp4, wmv

I have done some research on converting mp4 to wmv in java but have not found anything but advertisements on applications that convert mp4 to wmv. I do not know where to start when converting videos in java and I would be most grateful if anyone could help. I'm not into fancy graphical java apps so just command line would do nicely. Thank you.

Comment: Need something that converts a directory of vids in mp4 to another directory of vids in wmv

Answer (score 0):

to convert  `mp4` to `wmv` take a look at [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [JFFMPEG](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/). Also you may want to look into mencoder and ffmpeg.